# Yii: requiring a .php file

Tags: php, yii

I develop a project with Yii.

I need to require a plain .php file (not component, not a class, just a regular sequence of PHP functions definitions). What is the correct way to do this under Yii framework? Should I use plain require_once()?

```
require_once(Yii::app()->basePath . '/extensions/my-php-file.php');
```

Right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

Example:

```
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/extensions/PearMail/Mail-1.2.0/Mail.php';
```

Comment: Require is not a function, no need for `()`: This is right: `require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/extensions/PearMail/Mail-1.2.0/Mail.php';`

Comment: @lin: I know it is a statement and not a function. Your version certainly looks more pleasing, but I don't think it matters which one you use (except for readability, maybe).

Comment: Yii::$app is the static var for the Yii2 Application class, 'yii\web\Application'.
i tried this and it worked for me 
require_once Yii::$app->basePath . '/extensions/PearMail/Mail-1.2.0/Mail.php';

Answer (score 6):

Method in your question is fine, but forces file location to be always in same folder.

Flexible `Yii::import` is intented for loading classes only, and only classes whose name is same as filename.

However if you want to use aliases to get path to file, you can still benefit from aliases by using `getPathOfAlias`, like that:

```
require_once Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.extensions.my-php-file') . '.php';
```

To include file relative to current file it is good to use `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` (php 5.3+)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/some-file.php';
```