# Yii2 how to include a php file in a Controller

Tags: php, yii2

in my Yii2 frame work project i want to include a php file. the file contain two function file name "encryptdecrypt.php" and save it in common\extension folder

```
<?
    public function encryptIt( $q ) {
        $cryptKey  = 'OrangeOnlineMedia';
        $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
        return( $qEncoded );
    }

    public function decryptIt( $q ) {
        $cryptKey  = 'OrangeOnlineMedia';
        $qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
        return( $qDecoded );
    }

    ?>
```

i include this line in controller page("CustomersController")

top of the page include using this line

```
$encFile =Yii::getAlias('@common'). '\extensions\encryptdecrypt.php';
require_once($encFile);
```

and  use the function in an action
code bellow

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Customers();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

        $model->password=encryptIt($model->password);            
        if($model->created_date==null)
        {
          $model->created_date=date('y-m-d') ; 
        }
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->customer_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

here i am getting the following error
"Call to undefined function backend\controllers\encryptIt()"

thanks

Comment: Helpful : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28236-loading-an-existing-php-file-of-functions/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282136/yii-requiring-a-php-file

Answer (score 6):

Yii2 Uses [PSR-4 AutoLoader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) Rule, so first save `Security.php`

In `common\extensions` folder, then open `Security.php` and create class in it.

```
<?php

namespace common\extensions;

class Security {

    public function encrypt(){
    // todo
    }

    public function decrypt(){
    // todo
    }

}
```

and then in your `CustomersController` action `Create` use it like this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Customers();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        $security = new \common\extensions\Security(); // <-- Create Object Here
        $model->password= $security->encrypt($model->password);            
        if($model->created_date==null)
        {
          $model->created_date=date('y-m-d') ; 
        }
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->customer_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

BTW in Yii2 you can generate secure password hash like this too:
`Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);`

Comment: here  I am using windows 10 and xampp.so i am getting path error ."Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException
Unable to find 'backend\components\Crypt' in file: E:\xampp\htdocs\pope-Admin/backend/components/Crypt.php. Namespace missing?". i don't know how to solve it.. thanks once again

Comment: You should specify namespace of this Crypt class

Answer (score 0):

try getting

```
 $encFile = Yii::getAlias('@common/extensions/encryptdecrypt.php');
```

try also

```
var_dump($encFile)
```

and check the pathname

Comment: not working...  its getting error..  $encFile = Yii::getAlias('@common\extensions\encryptdecrypt.php');

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using wrong folder.
As you mentioned file is in `common\extension folder`

```
$encFile =Yii::getAlias('@common'). '\extension\encryptdecrypt.php';
require_once($encFile);
```

Comment: sorry typing mistake. but in coding i type correctly.

Comment: `require_once(Yii::getAlias('@common').'/extensions/func.php');` must be used before class Defination and after namespace includation

Comment: see your php file..   not enclosed with`<?php ?>`

Answer (score -2):

Make use of [DOCUMENT_ROOT](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

#### Example

To include files regardless of server type, do this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .Yii::getAlias('@common/sub_directory/yourFileName.php');
// outputs something like: /var/www/YiiApp/common/sub_directory/yourFileName.php

# or 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .Yii::getAlias('@web/images/image.jpg');
// outputs something like: /var/www/YiiApp/web/images/image.jpg
```